# How to check, if one line from one document applies to the same line, but in another document

Tags: python, function, tkinter

> My previous problems have been solved by using classes instead of functions at some places. But one question still remains. How do I check, if one line from one document applies to the same line, but in another document? I have tried this and it does nothing and gives me no error code.

```
class Logging1(object):

    def __init__(self, enteruser, enterpass):
        self.enteruser = enteruser
        self.enterpass = enterpass

    def __call__(self):

        usernames1 = open("usernames.txt", "r")
        passwords2 = open("passwords.txt", "r")

        rowU = 0
        rowP = 0

        for x in usernames1:
            if x != self.enteruser.get():
                rowU += 1
            else:
                break

        for y in passwords2:
            if y != self.enterpass.get():
                rowP += 1
            elif rowP == rowU:
                logged = Label(root, text="Successful login!")
                logged.grid(row=5, column=1)
                break
```

Comment: _"This code probably has a lot of mistakes, as I am a begginer"_ That's correct and Stackoverflow is a Q&A platform for specific programming questions. This question is off-topic. You should use your debugger to step line by line through the code, analyze each problem and ask a specific question for each problem that you can't solve. Hints: `usernames1 and passwords2` does not do what you expect. Open files with `with open(...) as ...:`. `buttonreg = Button(root, text="Register", padx="30", pady="5", command=registering1)` calls the function `registering1` without arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error is being thrown since when the function is being called without passing those two variables `regEnterpass, regEnteruser`

I am not able to test since I'm on my tablet but does the following work? by creating a class which will store the two variables and use them when called

**update:** you could read the text files in the init and store them as a dictionary

```
class Logging1(object):

    def __init__(self, enteruser, enterpass):
        self.enteruser = enteruser
        self.enterpass = enterpass
        
        ## open usernames.txt and get usernames
        with open("usernames.txt", "r") as users_file:
            users = [user for user in users_file]

        ## open password.txt and get passwords
        with open("passwords.txt", "r") as password_file:
            passwords = [password for password in password_file]
        
        ## combine and store them in a dictionary 
        self.users_dict = dict(zip(users, passwords))

    def __call__(self):
        entered_user = self.enteruser.get() ## get entered username
        
        if self.users_dict.has_key(entered_user): ## valid username
            entered_pw = self.enterpass.get() ## get entered password
            
            stored_pw = self.users_dict[entered_user]
            
            if entered_pw == stored_pw: ## correct username and pw
                logged = Label(root, text="Successful login!")
                logged.grid(row=5, column=1)
            else: 
                pass ## incorrect password
                
        else: pass ## not a valid username
        
def register():

    regUsername = Label(root, text="Set username: ")
    regUsername.grid(row=0, column=0)
    regEnteruser = Entry(root)
    regEnteruser.grid(row=0, column=1)

    regPassword = Label(root, text="Set password: ")
    regPassword.grid(row=1, column=0)
    regEnterpass = Entry(root)
    regEnterpass.grid(row=1, column=1)
    
    registering1 = Logging1(regEnterpass, regEnteruser) ## create Registering1 object

    buttonreg = Button(root, text="Register", padx="30", pady="5", command=registering1)
    buttonreg.grid(row=2, column=1)

    return regEnterpass and regEnteruser
```

Comment: This has solved my main problem, thank you very much. I wouldn't think of using classes, but they are way more useful than one would think.

Comment: this work? I wouldn't store passwords in a txt doc btw and this is just a hacky fix to get your code to work the way it is currently set out, not sure you'd want to open the text doc every time